# Is it possible to use Envers 4 with Hibernate 3?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

Currently, we are using the version `3.6.9.Final` for all our Hibernate libraries, including Hibernate Envers for our audit revisions.

We want to move to the `4.1.8.Final` version (to use the `@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)` among others things), but *only* for Hibernate Envers. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work. When I modify an `@Audited` entity, Envers does not save the revision.

Maybe it's due to the definition of the listeners? With 3.6.9, I set the following properties in my `hibernate.properties` file:

```
hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert=org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.post-update=org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete=org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update=org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove=org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate=org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
```

As far as I know, the version 4 of Envers does not need these declarations anymore. Without them, I get no error, but the revision are not created. I can't set these declarations back, as the classes are not the same between v3 and v4 (especially `org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener` that does not exist anymore).

So is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible, you must use the same Hibernate and Envers versions.